# Reading from a File - Wrong File Type?

Tags: java, eclipse, file

I am having trouble reading from a simple text file and cannot seem to figure out why.  I have done this before, and I am unsure as to what the issue is.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CS2110TokenReader {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        File theFile = new File("data1.txt");
        Scanner scnFile = new Scanner(theFile);

        try {
            scnFile = new Scanner(theFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
        while (theFile.hasNext()) {
            String s1 = theFile.next();
            Double d1 = theFile.nextDouble();

            System.out.println(s1 + "   " + d1);
        }

    }

}
```

---

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method hasNext() is undefined for the type File
    The method next() is undefined for the type File
    The method nextDouble() is undefined for the type File

    at CS2110TokenReader.main(CS2110TokenReader.java:20)
```

---

It will not even scan for the next line.  That is my objective.  To scan and read.

Comment: What's the error/output?  What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
while (theFile.hasNext()) {  // change to `scnFile.hasNext()`
    String s1 = theFile.next();  // change to `scnFile.next()`
    Double d1 = theFile.nextDouble();  // change to `scnFile.nextDouble()`

    System.out.println(s1 + "   " + d1);
}
```

You are invoking the method of `Scanner` class on `File` reference. Replace `theFile` with `scnFile` in all the invocation.

Secondly, you are invoking `next()` and `nextDouble()`, but are only checking for `hasNext()` once. That may throw you `NoSuchElementException` at some point of time. Make sure that, you have an input to read, before you actually read it.

Comment: Thanks!  just awaiting the timer so i can give u the green checkmark

Comment: @SamuelKnox. You're welcome :) And don't worry when you get negative feedbacks on your questions. You should learn from every bit here. Questions are downvoted to show you that you can get the answers by searching for them yourselves. That way you will learn better. So, don't take it otherwise.